# Load Linux workspace in S-PLUS for Windows

Tags: splus

Is it possible to load an S-PLUS Linux workspace in Windows?

If I try it I get this error: "Problem in exists(name, where = db):
This directory has both Unix style __*nonfile and Windows style
_*_nonfi"

The __nonfi file is created when I first try to load that Linux
workspace in Windows.

Is there any way to convert it to a Windows workspace?

I'm using S-PLUS 8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tibco support gave me a solution:

1. Create a new Windows workspace
2. Attach the Linux workspace

   `attach("C:\\Linux\\Workspace\\Path")`
3. Copy the contents of the Linux workspace to the Windows workspace

   `objs <- objects(2)`

   `for (i in objs) assign(i, value=get(i, where=2), where=1)`

   `objs <- objects(2, meta=1)`

   `for (i in objs) assign(i, value=get(i, where=2, meta=1), where=1, meta=1)`

Almost everything was copied. There were problems with functions named like `lBounds<-`, which were renamed to `lBounds_-`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for certain, but that won't stop me from wildly speculating:

The __nonfi file lists what's in the workspace.  You can open it with a text editor and look at the contents.  It might be possible to either manipulate the unix version (e.g. using dos2unix) or else copy the contents over into your new file.

That said, I doubt that this will work since some of the S-Plus files are in binary format, and I have run into trouble in the past when I have tried to manually change the __nonfi file.  This question might be better served by Tibco technical support.

Please update us here if you get an answer.